# Getting first value in a returned object with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using the command:

```
$hostnames = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "app-rg" -Name "app" |
               Select-Object -Property hostnames
```

To return the list of hostnames with an azure web app as below:

```
HostNames : {a.arup.com, a.internet.trafficmanager.net, a.azurewebsites.net}
```

However, I am interested in getting the first domain (`a.arup.com`).  How would this be done with powershell?

Comment: Are you looking to only get the first member or members that match that domain?

Answer (score 9):

In powershell, when you reference properties of an item in a list, you interact with them as a list.  So you can simply do the following:

```
$hostnames = (Get-AzureRmWebApp).HostNames
$hostnames[0]
```

To get the first one.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. So just treat it as an array and use an indexer.

Comment: or `$hostname = (Get-AzureRmWebApp).HostNames[0]`

Answer (score 9):

There is always an alternative in PowerShell:

```
$hostnames = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "app-rg" -Name "app" |
           Select-Object -ExpandProperty hostnames -First 1
```